# survey monkey iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, survey, surveymonkey

I have a swift based project and need to work with Survey Monkey SDK. I have tried to import the SDK manually as an external frameworks one time and also installed it through pod dependency the other time. However I could not access the SDK as importable module from my swift classes. So I have created an objc-swift bridging header file and get access to the framework's classes. I can display a survey. But no event is triggered when the user finishes filling out the survey. I have implemented `- (void)respondentDidEndSurvey:(SMRespondent *)respondent error:(NSError *) error;` But the block does not seem to be executed. Here is the class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <SurveyMonkeyiOSSDK/SurveyMonkeyiOSSDK.h>
#import "SurveyViewController.h"
#import "ABC-Swift.h"

#define SURVEY_HASH @"SSSSSSS"

@interface SurveyViewController () <SMFeedbackDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) SMFeedbackViewController * feedbackController;

@end

@implementation SurveyViewController

- (NSArray*)getSurveyResponse {

  return [NSArray new];
}

- (void)displaySurvey: (UIViewController *)context {
   _feedbackController = [[SMFeedbackViewController alloc] 
  initWithSurvey:SURVEY_HASH];
  _feedbackController.delegate = self;
  [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
  [_feedbackController scheduleInterceptFromViewController:context withAppTitle:SAMPLE_APP];
  [_feedbackController presentFromViewController:context animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)respondentDidEndSurvey:(SMRespondent *)respondent error:(NSError *) error {
if (respondent != nil) {
    if(respondent.completionStatus == SMCompletionStatusComplete){
        NSLog(@"User answered all questions");
        //logic goes here

    }
    SMQuestionResponse * questionResponse = respondent.questionResponses[0];

    NSString * questionID = questionResponse.questionID;
    if ([questionID isEqualToString:FEEDBACK_QUESTION_ID]) {
        SMAnswerResponse * answerResponse = questionResponse.answers[0];
        NSString * rowID = answerResponse.rowID;
        if ([rowID isEqualToString:FEEDBACK_FIVE_STARS_ROW_ID] || [rowID isEqualToString:FEEDBACK_FOUR_STARS_ROW_ID]) {

        }
        else {

        }
    }
}
else {

}

}



@end
```

I have created an objc based project and tried the same function, it worked as expected. So in swift based project how can I get respondent's answer when the survey ends?

Comment: How/where are you calling displaySurvey()? I'm wondering if the SurveyViewController might be getting deallocated before the respondentDidEndSurvey delegate method can be fired. Otherwise not sure what's going on, your code looks ok to me.

Comment: here is the interface class

`#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface SurveyViewController : NSObject  

- (void) displaySurvey: (UIViewController *)context;
- (NSArray*) getSurveyResponse;
@end`

I want the `displaySurvey()` function to be accessible from a swift file. The caller of this function is a viewController which will stay displayed even after survey completion.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the `@interface SurveyViewController` class extends `NSObject`. So I changed it to a subclass of `UIViewController` on top of which the survey monkey view is presented. So the parent view will not be deallocated before the `delegate` method is triggered. Thanx @bleiken for the hint.